# OSM labels look as red point in geoserver preview layer. Why?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, layers

I've imported shp directory files of OSM to geoserver and the city label layer look like red dots instead of showing labels of street names. Is there a fix for this ? (should I declare this layer kml instead of openlayers ?)

Comment: support your question with some screenshots for some ideas.I think it might be more understandable..

Comment: If answer won't solve the label issue , I will .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red points are the default point style that GeoServer will use when you don't ask for anything else. So you need to tell GeoServer what you would like it to draw.

It sounds as though you would like it to be a label in which case you'll need to create an [SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-introduction.html) file with a [TextSymbolizer](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/textsymbolizer.html) in it.

See the [SLD cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/) for an [example](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/points.html#point-with-styled-label).